# Manipulating other list items in ListView based on what item is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment containing a ListView with a custom adapter. My goal is to manipulate child views of the list item (to show shadows). If an item is clicked, the list item view before and after have to be manipulated by changing the visibility of the view(s) creating the shadow(s).

I can successfully get a reference and change the visibility, but the problem is that I can not get a reference to the views above and below the current item (since the shadows are added to those to create the shadow effect as desired).

I am using an onItemClick listener on the mSettingsListView in the fragment.

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Debugging", "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment_list, container, false);
    final ViewGroup viewGroup = container;

    Log.d(getTag(), "Finding settingsListView");
    mSettingsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
    mSettingsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Debugging", "settingsListView onItemClick position: " + position);

            // Remove right shadow on current item when clicked
            View rightShadow = view.findViewById(R.id.settingsListRowShadowRight);
            rightShadow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Shadow to be shown when active list item is the last
            // Shadow is shown on item above and view below list
            Log.d("Debugging", "settingsListView onItemClick position else clause");

            // Add a shadow at the bottom of the list item ABOVE current
            View aboveView = parent.getAdapter().getView(position -1, view, viewGroup);
            View aboveViewShadow = aboveView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListRowShadowAbove);
            aboveViewShadow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Add a shadow at the top of the list item BELOW current
            View belowView = parent.getAdapter().getView(position +1, view, viewGroup);
            View belowViewShadow = belowView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListRowShadowBelow);
            belowViewShadow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Right now the shadow is not added to the list items above and below, but on the item that is clicked. Another quirk is that when an list item is clicked, it updates with the text of the list item just below.

**The list item layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/settingsListRowContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_list_view_listitem_selector">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_paddingTop"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_paddingBottom"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_paddingLeft"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_paddingRight">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settingsListAppLogo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_imageView_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_imageView_size"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_row_imageView_marginRight">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingsListAppName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settingsListAppLogo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="@string/giraf_settings_name"
                android:textSize="32dp" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Shadow showing ABOVE active list item -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsListRowShadowAbove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_shadowSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_list_view_shadow_top"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- Shadow showing BELOW active list item -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsListRowShadowBelow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_shadowSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_list_view_shadow_bottom"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- Right shadow showing on a list item when inactive -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsListRowShadowRight"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/giraf_settings_list_shadowSize"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_list_view_shadow_right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am not how to get the adapter to return a view at a certain position and if/how it should be inflated when getting a reference to it?

**EDIT:**
Just added the getView() method of custom adapter.

**getView method of custom adapter:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if(convertView == null)
        vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment_list_row, null);

    // Get current item in the list
    SettingsListItem item = mApplicationList.get(position);

    ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.settingsListAppLogo);
    TextView appNameText = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.settingsListAppName);

    // Setting all values in ListView
    appIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(item.appIcon);
    appNameText.setText(item.appName);

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Use `getView` of CustomAdapter. It gives you the `position` of current clicked element. You can use that position value to get position of other listitems.

Comment: After you're done with changes in Adapter items, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I am calling getView on parent, which should give me the custom adapter?

Comment: The items of the adapter is not changed. It is only the views in the listview that have to change based on the position of the item clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was that I was trying to use the adapter to get an reference to the views above and below the list item clicked. Instead I could find the appropriate views by using the getChildAt() method on the parent view (the listview itself).

It was as easy as writing:

```
View aboveView = parent.getChildAt(position -1)
View aboveViewShadow = aboveView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListRowShadowAbove);
aboveViewShadow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```